# Transactions via spring annotations - readonly or not?

Tags: spring, transactions, readonly

I've got in my project code similar to this

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public void tt() {
    dd();
}

@Transactional()
public void dd() {
    gg();
}

@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public void gg() {

}
```

Function dd is used both by other readonly transaction functions and not readonly functions. Assuming that transaction should extendend from execution of tt to gg - operations in dd will in be read-only transaction or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring's `AbstractPlatformTransactionManager` has a property named `validateExistingTransaction` that controls this behavior. Javadoc states that:

> When participating in an existing transaction (e.g. with PROPAGATION_REQUIRES or PROPAGATION_SUPPORTS encountering an existing transaction), this outer transaction's characteristics will apply even to the inner transaction scope. Validation will detect incompatible isolation level and read-only settings on the inner transaction definition and reject participation accordingly through throwing a corresponding exception.

Since default propagation for Spring `@Transactional` annotation is `REQUIRED` and default validation strategy is false, I expect Spring to use existing transaction created from `tt` method call in readonly mode.

If you want to have a read only transaction, then you have to annotate your method with:

```
  @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, readOnly=true)
```

Answer (score 6):

In this particular example, your question is moot.

The call to `dd()` from `tt()` will not pass the proxy boundary so no transactional advise will be applied to `dd()` (since it's a call inside the same instance). Same with the call to `gg()` from `dd()`. Consequently, only the call from outside to `tt()` would actually be transaction-advised (in your case, with `readOnly=true`) and that would be the transaction that would be used in the entire call-chain.

In the general case though, read the documentation hinted by @melihcelik - it explains the behavior.

Answer (score 3):

use `@Transactional(readoOnly = true)` if you are performing a get/select and not making any changes, this means that no locks will be applied (which is more efficent).

For updates/inserts/deletions/saves/merges I use (when a lock is required) :

```
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor=Exception.class)
```